# How to populate data on nav-tab in partial View in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have partial View where I have 2 nav-tab. On Each tab, I want to populate data based on Country.

Currently, I am getting following error:

> Insufficient stack to continue executing the program safely. This can
>   happen from having too many functions on the call stack or function on
>   the stack using too much stack space.

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ClsHome model = new ClsHome();

            return View(model);
        }

       public PartialViewResult EmployeeBasedCountry(int CountryId)
        {
           ClsHome clshome=new ClsHome();
            clshome.Country = CountryId;

            clshome.countries = CountryFilter(CountryId);          
           return PartialView("~/Views/Home/_pEmp.cshtml", clshome);
        }
```

Index View

```
@model EmpWebsite.Models.Home.ClsHome      

<div class="col-md-5">                 
   @Html.Partial("_pEmp")
</div>
```

Partial View

```
@model EmpWebsite.Models.Home.ClsHome  
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
            <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Tab1">India</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Tab2" style="width:auto">USA</a></li>            
        </ul>


       <div class="tab-content">
             <div id="Tab1" class="tab-pane fade">
              @Html.Action("EmployeeBasedCountry", new { @CountryId = "1" })
                <div class="panel">
                    <table class="table-striped">
                        <tr class="heading">
                            <th>
                                EmpId
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                EmpName
                            </th>

                        </tr>

                        @foreach (var item in Model)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    @item.EmpId
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <a>@item.EmpName</a>
                                </td>


                            </tr>
                        }

                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="Tab2" class="tab-pane fade">
              @Html.Action("EmployeeBasedCountry", new { @CountryId = "2" })
                <div class="panel">
                    <table class="table-striped">
                        <tr class="heading">
                            <th>
                                EmpId
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                EmpName
                            </th>

                        </tr>

                        @foreach (var item in Model)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    @item.EmpId
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <a>@item.EmpName</a>
                                </td>


                            </tr>
                        }

                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>         


        </div>
```

Comment: The `@Html.Action()` in your `_pEmp.cshtml` partial calls `EmployeeBasedCountry()` which returns `_pEmp.cshtml` which calls `@Html.Action()` which returns `_pEmp.cshtml` which calls `@Html.Action()` which returns `_pEmp.cshtml` and so on and so on

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Exactly happening what you said. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Maybe you meant to write `@Html.ActionLink` instead of `@Html.Action` in order to get an anchor tag.

Comment: Just remove the `@Html.Action()` in your partial

Comment: @StephenMuecke, how can I pass CountryId then? Please help me.

Comment: What are you wanting to do? If you want a link, the use `@Html.ActionLink()`

Comment: @StephenMuecke, When user clicks `Tab1` then it should pass `CountryId=1` and if `Tab2` is clicked then `CountryId=2` in my controller

Comment: Then create a link!

Comment: @StephenMuecke, you mean in spite of Action, I have to create ActionLink

Comment: `@Html.Action` [returns HTML string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703457.aspx), not just a link. Rendering an anchor link requires `@Html.ActionLink("linktext", "actionName", "controllerName", new { CountryId = x })`.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I created like this but when I click on it, it does not pass the `CountryId`. I removed the code inside `<ul>` and pasted this code `<li class="active">@Html.ActionLink("India", "EmployeeBasedCountry", "Home", new { @CountryId = "1" })</li>
  <li>@Html.ActionLink("USA", "EmployeeBasedCountry", "Home", new { @CountryId = "2" })</li>`

Comment: Because you are missing the 5th argument of `ActionLink()` - i.e. `@Html.ActionLink("India", "EmployeeBasedCountry", "Home", new { @CountryId = "1" , null })`

Comment: @StephenMuecke, it throws error `Cannot assign '<null>' to anonymous type property`

Comment: Sorry, `@Html.ActionLink("India", "EmployeeBasedCountry", "Home", new { @CountryId = "1" }, null )`

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I am getting the data now. But it displays the partial one, not the index page. Because I want this partial inside Index.

Comment: Then you have not wired up you tabs correctly

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Sorry to interrupt you. I have updated my partial view in the question. can you please have a look. Please guide me what I am missing there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176994/discussion-between-mvc-and-stephen-muecke).

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto, Sorry to disturb you. Can you please help me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51586606/why-view-is-getting-refreshed-when-i-click-on-partial-view-element-in-mvc?noredirect=1#comment90139332_51586606)